# Can I have two of the same variables in php.ini both not commented?

Tags: php

When making changes to a `php.ini` file, I've started adding all of my settings to the bottom of the file so that I have sort of a log of all of the changes I've made to make upgrading easier.

Well, now we want to upgrade our server to support a newer version of PHP and I'm wondering if I copy over my settings from the old `php.ini` to the new one, do I have to comment out the same variables above?

```
;PHP notes about this function here...
display_errors = On

;Custom changes
display_errors = Off
```

Do I have to comment out the first one?  Or will PHP know that I want errors Off?

Comment: yes. AFAIK the last one overrules. (You could have just tried it, in stead of asking)

Comment: It's a production environment, I don't want to mess with anything... so I have not tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last setting will take affect, so in this case `display_errors` will be off. However I would recommend commenting out the first declaration since this could easily confuse the next poor soul who is looking at the ini file.

Answer (score 1):

php.ini declarations are overwritable, and the last one to be parsed takes precendence. This is why some hosts allow you to place php.ini files in your local web folders to override the default php.ini (for such things as max upload size)

What your doing is perfectly fine